# Is declaring an empty array in vuejs data object correct way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I need multiple empty arrays and some predefined objects to go with a component. The below format for data object works for me. But I am unable to figure out if this is the right pattern and if it could have any other consequences.

Below is a partial code from a vue component I wrote.

```html
<template>
 //html
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "SomeComponent",
    data() {
        let dates = []
        let open = []
        let closed = []
        let replied = []
        let option = {
            title: {
                text: "Summary",
            },
            tooltip: {
                trigger: "axis",
            },
            legend: {
                data: [{
                        name: "Open",
                        icon: "circle"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Closed",
                        icon: "circle"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Replied",
                        icon: "circle"
                    },
                ],
            }
        }
        return {
            dates,
            open,
            closed,
            replied,
            option,
            theme,
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: If that is the data you need to display, then yes. I stick to initializing empty arrays for arrays and undefined for objects. Then in template v-for works automatically with empty lists and you can check objects with v-if directive.

Comment: I was mostly concerned with how the options initialisation makes the code unreadable. Would there be a cleaner or better way to organise data object? For example, initialising the object somewhere else and assign here or so? I am not sure what all vue does behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically generate it by iterating on it.
It will maybe make it more readable but also more complex.
That kind of pattern is not something shocking to me.

Meanwhile, I recommend more of something like this

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dates: [],
      open: [],
      closed: [],
      replied: [],
      option: {
        title: {
          text: 'Summary',
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'axis',
        },
        legend: {
          data: [
            {
              name: 'Open',
              icon: 'circle',
            },
            {
              name: 'Closed',
              icon: 'circle',
            },
            {
              name: 'Replied',
              icon: 'circle',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

The `return` inside of `data` written like that is important and also more readable (more on how you can find it in the documentation too).

Also, that way you will get all of your state reactive down the road if you mutate it with a `method` or alike.